# When database is not available what is the best way to store the value

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an API which is accepting the data which will be used by multiple users. I don't have a Database available what is the best approach to do so.
Asp.net core project

Comment: What do you mean by a database is not available? A database is simply where you store stuff.

Comment: Have you considered using Entity Framework w/ SqlLite? You'd just point it at the local sqllite db file. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli

Comment: It means, in case the database is not present currently but in future we might migrate this data to DB, what will be the best approach that can be followed now.

Comment: Let me try SQL Lite

Comment: @asawyer I am unable to create a db file.

Comment: Ok. Not really enough to go on here to give any advice. Maybe start with Why you cannot create a db file. I think you just fire up SSMS and create a new database to generate it. If you plan on later migrating your solution to a server resource EF/SqlLite would more or less make the swap over as simple as changing a connection string value in a config file. I believe code-first EF will create tables for you but you have to start with at least an empty database. I could be mistaken on that.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can use Files. Data will write in files, or you can Cookies, LocalStorage to store data.

Comment: storing in cache or file, which one do you feel is the best approach

Comment: It depends on your scenario. If you have limited number of records then I'll sugguest go for cache. If you have larger number then go for Files.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your data to a **file**,I think it will be more flexible and you can directly edit the file

content to modify your data, check my demo to save and get data from file to a list in web api

project:

```
[Route("/save")]
    public async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        string[] lines = { "First line", "Second line", "Third line" };
        using StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("SaveData.txt");

        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
                await file.WriteLineAsync(line);
        }
    }

    [Route("/getfile")]
    public async Task testAsync()
    {
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\****\SaveData.txt");

        List<string> mylist =new List<string>();

        System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of WriteLines2.txt = ");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            mylist.Add(line);
        } 
    }
```

And this is the official tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file

Result:

[image]